# What is 'Found' in Fail2Ban Log File?

Tags: ssh, logging, lamp, fail2ban

I have multiple instances like the following in /var/log/fail2ban.log:

```
2015-12-27 14:31:21,949 fail2ban.filter         [1020]: INFO    [sshd] Found ###.###.###.###
```

(Where # substitutes for a diversity of IP addresses.)

What exactly is the meaning of this log entry?  Particularly, what does `Found` denote?

I searched here and http://www.fail2ban.org for an explanation of the log file.  If I've missed an obvious information source for this question, my apologies - please point me in the right direction.

Here is the config for FailRegex in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.config:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error) for .* from <HOST>( via \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sFailed \S+ for .*? from <HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?(: (ruser .*|(\S+ ID \S+ \(serial \d+\) CA )?\S+ %(__md5hex)s(,$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)s[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)srefused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>: 3: \S+: Auth fail$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*$
        ^(?P<__prefix>%(__prefix_line)s)User .+ not allowed because account is locked<SKIPLINES>(?P=__prefix)(?:error: )?Received disconnect from$
        ^(?P<__prefix>%(__prefix_line)s)Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for .+? \[preauth\]<SKIPLINES>(?P=__prefix)(?:error: )?Co$
        ^(?P<__prefix>%(__prefix_line)s)Connection from <HOST> port \d+(?: on \S+ port \d+)?<SKIPLINES>(?P=__prefix)Disconnecting: Too many authe$
        ^%(__prefix_line)spam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;\s*logname=\S*\s*uid=\d*\s*euid=\d*\s*tty=\S*\s*ruser=\S*\s*rhost=<HOST$
```

Comment: in filter.d/sshd.conf, what is your FailRegex? http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters

Comment: (Added the FailRegex to the original post.)

Comment: ssh is the hackers favorite first choice, according to my logs 10 to 1.  It is likely one of these connecting to your system.  I have over 10,000+ ip just for ssh.

Comment: do any of the other regex patterns in the filter.d/sshd.conf contain the word 'Found'?

Comment: Curiously, the string 'Found' does not appear in sshd.conf or any file within /etc/fail2ban.  @cybernard I definitely agree; the problem is that fail2ban is already banning ssh attempts, and password-based ssh is disabled on the system (key-based ssh only).

Comment: The "Found xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" message means, that the fail2ban filter found a line that matches failregex in the given filter/jail logfile.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Found xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` message means, that the fail2ban filter found a line that matches failregex in the given filter/jail logfile.

For example if the log shows

```
2016-03-16 15:35:51,527 fail2ban.filter         [1986]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.2.3.4
2016-03-16 15:35:51,817 fail2ban.filter         [1986]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.2.3.4
2016-03-16 15:35:52,537 fail2ban.actions        [1986]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 1.2.3.4
```

The two first `Found` mean, that IP address 1.2.3.4 was found 2 times in the given sshd log (e.g. /var/log/auth.log) and that the entry in the logfile matches `failregex`in the filter `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf`

As I have configured to ban after 2 failed ssh-attemtps, the 3rd line shows, that IP 1.2.3.4 has been banned after those 2 found occurrences.

How I found out about this:

In the python sources of fail2ban (in Debian this is in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/`) do this:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/

grep -r "\[%s\] Found" *
```

In the python file "server/filter.py" on line 937 you find the corresponding log function:

```
def processLineAndAdd(self, line, date=None):
  [..]
  logSys.info("[%s] Found %s" % (self.jail.name, ip))
  [..]
```

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this reply was posted, but I just came back to it again.  It's such a lucid, complete response - thanks.